# Como implementar sobrecarga dos operadores << e >> em C++?

Tags: c++, classes, sobrecarga

Olá, estou fazendo um exercício que consiste no seguinte enunciado:

[image: Enunciado do exercício]

Desculpem por colocar um print, mas não consegui selecionar o texto e seria um trabalho desnecessário digitar tudo aqui.

Enfim, eu fiz a classe e implementei a sobrecarga dos operadores +, -, * e /, porém não estou conseguindo fazer a parte dos operadores << e >>, utilizados no Cin e no Cout.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class MeuInt{

    public:
        MeuInt(int i=0);
        int operator+(int);
        int operator-(int);
        int operator*(int);
        int operator*(MeuInt);
        int operator/(int);
        friend ostream &operator>>(ostream&, const MeuInt&);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream&, MeuInt&);

        int getInteiro();
        void setInteiro(int);

    private:
        int inteiro;
    };

    MeuInt::MeuInt(int i){
        inteiro = 1;
    }



    int MeuInt::operator+(int x){
        inteiro = x + inteiro;
        return inteiro;
    }
    int MeuInt::operator-(int x){
        inteiro = x - inteiro;
        return inteiro;
    }
    int MeuInt::operator*(int x){
        inteiro = x * inteiro;
        return inteiro;
    }

int MeuInt::operator*(MeuInt x){
    inteiro = x * inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}


int MeuInt::operator/(int x){
    inteiro = x / inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}

int MeuInt::getInteiro(){
    return inteiro;
}

void MeuInt::setInteiro(int x){
    inteiro = x;
}

MeuInt calcDelta(MeuInt a, MeuInt b, MeuInt c){
    MeuInt delta = b*b - a * c * 4;
    return delta;   
}

ostream &operator>>(ostream& saida, const MeuInt& meuint){
    output << meuint.getInteiro();
    return output;
}

istream &operator>>(istream& entrada, MeuInt& meuint){

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MeuInt inteiro1(10);
    MeuInt A, B, C;

    int c = inteiro1 + 1;

    cout << "inteiro1 + 1: ";
    cout << c << endl;

    cout << "Entre com as variáveis: " << endl;
    cout << "A: ";
    cin >> A;

    cout << "B: ";
    cin >> B;

    cout << "C: ";
    cin >> C;

    return 0;
}
```

Com o código acima, a IDE está retornando os seguintes erros:

- Na função 'std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream&, const MeuInt&)':
- 'output' não foi declarado anteriormente
- Passando 'const MeuInt' como 'this' argumento de 'int MeuInt::getInteiro()'       descarta qualificadores
- Na função 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, MeuInt&)':
- Esta função não é void e não foi encontrada uma expressão de retorno

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: você já tentou resolver os erros ? pelo menos o primeiro deles é auto-explicativo: "output' não foi declarado anteriormente"...

Comment: Sim, esse era óbvio e eu acabei colocando sem perceber. Resolvi os erros e coloquei o código em uma resposta. Obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi os problemas acima, então deixo aqui o código caso alguém precise um dia. Só falta implementar os métodos que retornam as raízes da equação, estou tentando fazer isso.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MeuInt{

    public:
        MeuInt(int i=0);
        int operator+(int);
        int operator-(int);
        int operator*(int);
        int operator*(MeuInt);
        int operator/(int);


        int getInteiro();
        void setInteiro(int);

    private:
        int inteiro;
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const MeuInt&);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream&, MeuInt&);
};

MeuInt::MeuInt(int i){
    inteiro = 1;
}



int MeuInt::operator+(int x){
    inteiro = x + inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}
int MeuInt::operator-(int x){
        inteiro = x - inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}
int MeuInt::operator*(int x){
    inteiro = x * inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}

int MeuInt::operator*(MeuInt x){
    inteiro = x * inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}


int MeuInt::operator/(int x){
    inteiro = x / inteiro;
    return inteiro;
}

int MeuInt::getInteiro(){
    return inteiro;
}

void MeuInt::setInteiro(int x){
    inteiro = x;
}

MeuInt calcDelta(MeuInt a, MeuInt b, MeuInt c){
    MeuInt delta = b*b - a * c * 4;
    return delta;

}

ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, const MeuInt& meuint){
    out << meuint.inteiro;

    return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream& in, MeuInt& meuint){

    in >> meuint.inteiro;

    return in;
}



int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MeuInt inteiro1(10);
    MeuInt A, B, C;

    int c = inteiro1 + 1;

    cout << "inteiro1 + 1: ";
    cout << c << endl;

    cout << "Entre com as variáveis: " << endl;
    cout << "A: ";
    cin >> A;

    cout << "B: ";
    cin >> B;

    cout << "C: ";
    cin >> C;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No header da função:  `ostream &operator>>(ostream& saida, const MeuInt& meuint)`
Procure trocar o operador `>>` por `<<`, pois este é que é usado em operações de saída. O problema `'output' não foi declarado anteriormente`, é porque você passou o parâmetro do tipo `ostream&` com o nome `saida`, e na função você esta usando com o nome `output`. Já na função `istream& operator>>(std::istream&, MeuInt&)`, o problema como você disse é porque a função não é void, por isso você deve retornar um elemento, no caso uma implementação do operador de inserção `istream& entrada`.

Comment: Sim, depois de um tempo olhando o código percebi que estava >> em vez de <<, acontece... Agora consegui resolver os problemas, obrigada.